# Python: replacing method in calendar module

Tags: python, calendar

I'm trying to replace two methods in calendar module:

```
import calendar


c = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.MONDAY)
def ext_formatday(self, day, weekday, *notes):
    if day == 0:
        return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>'
    if len(notes) == 0:
        return '<td class="%s">%d<br /></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day)
    else:
        return '<td class="%s">%d<br />%s</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, notes)

def ext_formatweek(self, theweek, *notes):
    if len(notes) == 0:
        s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd) for (d, wd) in theweek)
    else:
        s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd, notes) for (d, wd) in theweek)
    return '<tr>%s</tr>' % s 

c.formatday = ext_formatday
c.formatweek = ext_formatweek

print c.formatmonth(2012,1,"foobar")
```

This won't work - could somebody point me to relevant literature or point out what I'm doing wrong?
I'm trying to implement Alan Hynes suggestion from the following thread: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101524/python-calendar-htmlcalendar/1458077#1458077)
It way too late for me to think straight and I've been dancing around that problem for over an hour.

Thanks in advance,
Jakub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to replace the methods; what Alan Hynes suggested was to *subclass* HTMLCalendar:

```
class MyCustomCalendar(calendar.HTMLCalendar):

    def formatday(self, day, weekday, *notes):
        ...

    def formatweek(self, theweek, *notes):
        ...

c = MyCustomCalendar(calendar.MONDAY)
```

This will create a new derived class (MyCustomCalendar), which inherits all HTMLCalendar's methods and attributes, but defines its own versions of `formatday` and `formatweek`.

You can read more about [Inheritance](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) in the Python tutorial, or elsewhere on the web. It's an important tool in Python (and object-oriented programming in general), and many libraries are designed around it.

Comment: Now I know why my first version didn't work - i forget about 'calendar.' before HTMLCalendar. 
Thank Piet you for that example and thanks everybody for the interest in my noob question!
good wknd to you all

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the method at the class instead of the instance.

Like this:

```
import calendar                                                                                                 


def ext_formatday(self, day, weekday, *notes):                                                                  
    if day == 0:                                                                                                
        return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>'                                                                  
    if len(notes) == 0:                                                                                         
        return '<td class="%s">%d<br /></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day)                                 
    else:                                                                                                       
        return '<td class="%s">%d<br />%s</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, notes)                        

def ext_formatweek(self, theweek, *notes):                                                                      
    if len(notes) == 0:                                                                                         
        s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd) for (d, wd) in theweek)                                               
    else:                                                                                                       
        s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd, notes) for (d, wd) in theweek)                                        
    return '<tr>%s</tr>' % s                                                                                    

calendar.HTMLCalendar.formatday = ext_formatday                                                                 
calendar.HTMLCalendar.formatweek = ext_formatweek                                                               

c = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.MONDAY)                                                                      
print c.formatmonth(2012,1,"foobar")
```

Answer (score 1):

*Updated* to use `types.MethodType` as suggested by Aaron in the comments.

Try:

```
import types
c.formatday = types.MethodType(ext_formatday, c, calendar.HTMLCalendar)
```

See the [types module](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) docs.  To see why it was failing:

```
In [53]: class A(object):
   ....:     def foo(self): pass

In [54]: def bar(self): pass

In [55]: a = A()

In [56]: a.foo
Out[56]: <bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x030D4770>>

In [57]: a.foo = bar

In [58]: a.foo
Out[58]: <function bar at 0x030C3EB0>

In [59]: aa = A()

In [60]: aa.foo.im_class, aa.foo.im_func, aa.foo.im_self
Out[60]:
(<class '__main__.A'>,
 <function foo at 0x030EE6F0>,
 <__main__.A object at 0x030D4910>)

In [61]: a.foo.im_class
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'im_class'
```

Comment: the new module is deprecated. use `types.MethodType` instead. It's constructor takes the same arguments and `new.instancemethod`.