# Customizing calendar.HTMLCalendar in a Django Project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am using HTMLCalendar to add a calendar to my django project. The calendar is showing perfectly fine but I want to add some customization to it like adding button with links. As a simple example I want to add a divider after the month and I want to add a condition so that if an event is on a specific date to have a button around the number of the month. I have found some very old answers but I am not sure how to actually implement.

Similar answers:[python calendar.HTMLCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101524/python-calendar-htmlcalendar)

Here is the current view:

```
class home(ListView):
    model = Workout
    template_name = 'app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'workouts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        year= datetime.now().year
        month=datetime.now().month
        cal=HTMLCalendar().formatmonth(year,month)
        context['cal']=cal
        print(cal)
        return context
```

here is the current outcome:

[image]

Here is the template I am sure there is an easier way that I did not yet find to add padding:

```
              <center>{{ cal|safe }}</center>
              <style>
                .month{
                text-align: center;
                }
                .mon{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
                .tue{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
                .wed{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
                .thu{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
                .fri{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
                .sat{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
                .sun{
                padding-left:15px;
                }
              </style>
            </div>
```

This is the required outcome or similar to it:

[image]

***My question:***

How can I customize the HTMLCalendar so that I can reach the image showing and where should I be writing the conditions for changing the colors in the template or better in the views

Answer (score 0):

One solution is perhaps to generate the HTML calendar, then parse the HTML to give each `<td>` element an ID (corresponding to the day number). Then you can format the elements by addressing them via this ID.

So after parsing, the html should look like this:

```
....
<td class="mon" id="day11">11</td>
<td class="tue" id="day12">12</td>
....
```

This could be achieved e.g. like this:

```py
from calendar import monthrange

mr = monthrange(year, month)
for i in range(1, mr[1]+1):
    x = str(i)
    cal = cal.replace(f'>{x}<', f'id="day{x}">{x}<')
```